# linq select from database where ID in an ArrayList

Tags: linq, arraylist

I have an array-list that contains some UserID.
I need a query like this:

```
vat tmp= users.select(a=> a.UserID in (arraylist));
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it's actually in an `ArrayList`, you should create a `List<T>` or array first. Then you can use `Contains`:

```
// Use the appropriate type, of course.
var ids = arraylist.Cast<string>().ToList();
var tmp = users.Select(a => ids.Contains(a.UserID));
```

While using `Contains` on the plain `ArrayList` may well *compile*, I would expect it to fail at execution time, assuming `users` is an `IQueryable<>`.

Comment: You're right that it doesn't work in most cases. I've had to convert a list of items into a delimited string and call contains on the string. Which isn't a foolproof solution as you can get false positives if you're not careful.

Comment: @Yuck: I was saying that using an `ArrayList` won't work. Using the `List<T>` should be fine with most LINQ providers, I believe. Not that the OP has said what the context is...

Comment: I use this code and it works. thank u all

    List<long> list =new List<long>();
    var query = from n in users where list.Contains(n.ID) select n ;

Comment: I crufted up a quick sample with Jon's code above and one interesting thing to me was that written the way it is the var tmp is of type IEnumerable<Boolean>, I think because of the Contains.  I had to change it to use a Where instead of the Contains to get back a List of the type contained in the ArrayList, like this: var tmp = users.Where(a => ids.Contains(a.UserID));

Answer (score 6):

```
List<long> list =new List<long>(); 
var selected = from n in users where list.Contains(n.ID) select n ;
```

OR

```
var selected = users.Where(a=> list.Contains(a.ID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used.

```
public static IEnumerable<SettingModel> GetSettingBySettingKeys(params string[] settingKey)
    {
        using (var db = new BoxCoreModelEntities())
        {
            foreach (var key in settingKey)
            {
                var key1 = key;
                yield return Map(db.Settings.Where(s => s.SettingKey == key1).First());
            }
        }
    }
```